# Парсер ФИО из строки

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как из строки вырвать ФИО.

Условие:

1. ФИО может иметь разные форматы: полностью заглавными буквами , полностью строчными
2. Фамилии могут быть самыми разными, поэтому выбирать их по окончанию иванОВА , иванОВ не получится (есть фамилия Мячин, Елинек, Асатрян и т.д.)
3. Фамилии не могут быть сокращены. ФИО пишется только полностью, сокращений нет.

Пример текста

> (л/с 123456789) Долг с Порозова Екатерина Екатеринова 12345, Россия, , , г. Никитинкск, , ул. 40-летия Победы, дом 144, , кв. 1078 по и/д 1234567890- от 01.01.01. ИП 12345678-УК

Необходимо из данного текста выдернуть Прозорова Екатерина  Екатеринова

> (ИНН 123456789; КПП 0); : ОЛЬШЕВСКИЙ ВАСИЛИЙ ВЛАДИМИРОВИЧ РОССИЯ,,ЯРОСЛАВСКАЯ ОБЛ.,,Г. ЯРОСЛАВЛЬ,,УЛ. БЛЮНИХЕРА,Д.1,,КВ.1986 Исполнительный лист №012340 от 30.01.2006. Без НДС.

ОЛЬШЕВСКИЙ ВАСИЛИЙ ВЛАДИМИРОВИЧ

Есть сервисы с API позволяющие это сделать?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ez79s7/1 - тут можно потренероваться и составить подходящее выражение

Comment: Dadata умеет это и дедуплицировать данные. Куча статей на хабре, сам сервис где-то тут: https://dadata.ru/api/suggest/name/ Качественно, платно.

Comment: Я бы не использовал регулярные выражения. А написал бы простой парсер на C#, заодно строку можно разложить в объект (на случай, если потом понадобятся другие реквизиты долга, помимо фамилии). Регулярные выражения не универсальны (где гарантия, что на 3-м примере оно сработает?). А парсер можно будет менять при усложнении примеров. Смысла не вижу в сторонних библиотеках для такой простой задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Библиотека Natasha к вашим услугам
https://github.com/natasha/natasha

Советую версию 0.10.0, если интересуют только фио

Comment: Плюсую `Natasha`, вручную сочинять регекспы можно замучиться, лучше взять готовое решение.

Comment: А для дотнета такая есть?